# How to make geom_point specific shapes for each condition using scale_shape_manual?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a PCA on ggplot and I need to make the points specific shapes per condition. I have used the following code:

```
cisr5_plot <- ggplot(cisr5scores, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2))+
  geom_point(size= 4.5, aes(fill=cisr5$Treatment), shape =21, colour="black")+
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("Cells","HIV-1 R5", "LPS", "M. bovis", "H37Rv", "HN878", "CDC1551", "EU127"),
                      values=c("Cells" = "black", "HIV-1 R5" = "ivory3", "LPS" = "royalblue4", "M. bovis" = "darkcyan", "HN878" = "sandybrown", "H37Rv" = "seagreen4", "EU127" = "darkorange1", "CDC1551" = "orangered1"))+
  xlab(paste("PC1 ", "(",cisr5exp12[1],"%", sep=""))+
  ylab(paste("PC1 ", "(",cisr5exp12[2],"%", sep=""))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 24, family = "sans"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 22, family = "sans"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour ="black", size = 22, family = "sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour ="black", size = 22, family = "sans"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 24, family = "sans"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

To create this plot:

[image]

But I want to change each individual shape, and i have tried for ages with scale_shape_manual and it just changes them all to black. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: look here : http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/shape

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but unfortuantely i cant seem to figure it our.  I added this to my code `cisr5_plot <- ggplot(cisr5scores, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2))+
  geom_point(size= 4.5, aes(fill=cisr5$Treatment), shape =21, colour="black")+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("Cells" = "21", "HIV-1 R5" = "21", "LPS" = "24", "M. bovis" = "23", "HN878" = "24", "H37Rv" = "21", "EU127" = "24", "CDC1551" = "21"))+` but that didnt seem to work

Comment: Please post some sample data using `dput()` in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using this code, to call the shape in aesthetic based on treatment, then giving manual shapes.

```
cisr5_plot <- ggplot(cisr5scores, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2))+
  geom_point(size= 4.5, aes(fill=cisr5$Treatment, shape = cisr5$Treatment), colour="black")+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("Cells" = 21,"HIV-1 R5" = 21,"LPS" = 24,"M. bovis" = 23,"HN878" = 24,"H37Rv" = 21,"EU127" = 24,"CDC1551" = 21))+
  scale_fill_manual(breaks=c("Cells","HIV-1 R5", "LPS", "M. bovis", "H37Rv", "HN878", "CDC1551", "EU127"),
                      values=c("Cells" = "black", "HIV-1 R5" = "ivory3", "LPS" = "royalblue4", "M. bovis" = "darkcyan", "HN878" = "sandybrown", "H37Rv" = "seagreen4", "EU127" = "darkorange1", "CDC1551" = "orangered1"))+
  xlab(paste("PC1 ", "(",cisr5exp12[1],"%", ")", sep=""))+
  ylab(paste("PC1 ", "(",cisr5exp12[2],"%", ")", sep=""))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 24, family = "sans"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text = element_text(size = 22, family = "sans"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour ="black", size = 22, family = "sans"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour ="black", size = 22, family = "sans"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "black", size = 24, family = "sans"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```